# Error setting dynamic metadata using NextJS app router

Tags: next.js, metadata, meta-tags, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am having multiple dynamic routes in my nextjs application like /[product] and /u/[user]

I am using this code to generate dynamic meta tags for /[product]

```
import React from 'react'
import { host } from '@/host';
import Product from '../../../../components/Product';

export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/product/details`, {
method: "POST",

    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ product: params.product }),

});
const json = await response.json();
return {
title: `${json.product.name} - ${json.product.tagline} | Product Information and Reviews `,
description: json.product.description,
keywords: json.product.tags,

    openGraph: {
      type: "website",
      siteName: "myapp",
      title:  `${json.product.name} - ${json.product.tagline} | Product Information and Reviews `,
      description: json.product.description,
      images: json.product.thumbnail
    
    },
    twitter: {
      card: "summary",
      title:  `${json.product.name} - ${json.product.tagline} | Product Information and Reviews `,
      description: json.product.description,
      images: json.product.thumbnail
    
    },

};
}

const Page = ({params}) =\> {
return (
\<Product params={params} \>\</Product\>
)
}

export default Page
```

I am getting the correct response for my product page but when I use a similar code for my /u/[user] page, I am getting an errror :

Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { host } from "@/host";
import UserProfile from "../../../../components/UserProfile";

export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/user/fetchuniqueuser`, {
method: "POST",

    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ profile: params.user }),

});
const json = await response.json();
return {
title: `${json.fetchuniqueuser.username}`,
};
}

const UserPage = ({ params }) =\> {
return \<UserProfile params={params}\>\</UserProfile\>;
};

export default UserPage;
```

However when I hit the same api call from my client side component inside my useEffect hook, I am getting the desired data:

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchUser() {
            const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/user/fetchuniqueuser`, {
                method: "POST",

                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ profile: params.user }),
            });
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log(json)
            setuser(json.fetchuniqueuser)
        }
        fetchUser()
    }, [params])
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here

Also is there any easier method to set dynamic meta in nextjs app router ?

Please help me

I expected that generateMetadata will work in multiple dynamic routes but its not working as expected.